# C linker error : .\_build\ble_app_hids_keyboard.axf: Error: L6200E: Symbol UX_captureStarted multiply defined (by sens.o and main.o)

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors

Hi I'm trying to compile my program but always get this linker error:

```
.\_build\ble_app_hids_keyboard.axf: Error: L6200E: Symbol UX_captureStarted multiply defined (by sens.o and main.o)
..\_build\ble_app_hids_keyboard.axf: Error: L6200E: Symbol UX_captureStarted multiply defined (by algorithm.o and main.o).
```

here is the structure of my code:

sens.h

```
extern int8_t UX_captureStarted = 0;
```

sens.c

```
int8_t UX_captureStarted = 0;
```

algorithm.h

```
#include "sens.h"
// some processing using UX_captureStarted
```

main.c

```
#include "algorithm.h"
//some processing using UX_captureStarted
```

I got the same linker error with several other variables declared with the same structur as UX_captureStarted. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has multiple instances of those variables, causing linking problem. Check your compiling order, and try to make a one source for those. Also you might want to delete the defining line in sens.c.